# Unable to mock a JSON response in Spring RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, resttemplate

I'm trying to mock a string in RestTemplate response, But I'm getting below error in code. Please provide inputs.

## Error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced argument matcher detected here:

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
   when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
   doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
   verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

The Above error happened in this line:

## Error in below line Code:

```
    when(this.userProfileClientRestTemplateProvider.currentUserProfileWithPermissionsRestTemplate()
               .exchange(
                any(RequestEntity.class),eq(String.class)))                .thenReturn(mockResponseEntityFromFile("com/cnanational/dealerplanadmin/service/applyRuleSetsToDealer/user-permissions.json", 
String.class, ResponseEntity.ok()));
```

Comment: share full class and logs. ```this.userProfileClientRestTemplateProvider.currentUserProfileWithPermissionsRestTemplate()``` is this mocked object?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you make use of some mockito matcher like `any(Object)` or `anyString()` outside of the mock object.

You either have to mock the object you want to use the matcher in (most of the time you want to mock objects where you tended to use matcher parameters in the first place) or you put a fixed value instead of the matcher.

Another possibility for this error message would be if you try to mock a `final` method.

For more detailed answers we need to see your code.

Please let us know if we could help you out or provide more information to help us solving your problem.